# How do I sort a GtkTreeModelFilter?

Tags: sorting, gtk, gtktreeview

I have a `GtkListStore` with a `GtkTreeModelFilter` wrapped around this, to filter out certain rows. I then put this filter inside a `GtkTreeView`.

This causes my `GtkTreeView` to be not-sortable, as `GtkTreeModelFilter` does not implement `GtkTreeSortable`.

How do I make it so I can still sort the rows in my `GtkTreeView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap a `GtkTreeModelSort` around your `GtkTreeModelFilter`. Then add this wrapper to the `GtkTreeView`.

In summary, you would have a `GtkListStore` inside a `GtkTreeModelFilter` inside a `GtkTreeModelSort` inside a `GtkTreeView`.

Comment: This may also be of interest as a different way to achieve similar results: [Bloerg: A Sorted and Filtered GtkTreeView](https://bloerg.net/2012/10/23/sorted-and-filtered-tree-view.html)